# would queue.empty() and queue.full() guarantee thread safe if I only 1 read thread and 1 write thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, queue, mutex, shared-memory

Usually for memory that is accessed by multi-thread, we would use mutex to lock it. 
But seems below logic is OK without mutex, but not sure if race condition or potential issue would happen for below pseudo code without mutex lock.

```
queue q;
int thread_read(){
    if(!q.empty())
       a = q.front();
       q.pop();
}

int thread_write(b){
    if(!q.full())
       p.push(b)
}
```

Comment: When asking questions about multi-threading, post real code.

Comment: There is no "full" method on the `std::queue` adapter, so are you using something else? And the interleaving of accessors to the object makes individual lockdowns a second priority.  Fyi, `std::queue` is an *adapter*, and enshrouds a template-parameterized sequence container (defaulting to `std::deque`). Like all the other containers in the standard library, it, too, is *not* guaranteed thread-safe for volatile concurrency.

Comment: Nor do you want a library container to be thread safe. It will be impossible to get the synchronization granularity right for all users, so you might as well leave it out and let the users synchronize according to their needs in a wrapper.  Java ran into this years ago with their library `Vector`.

Comment: I was thinking implementing full() function by myself, then I figured out that full() and empty() will need counter to decide whether it is empty or full, while this counter also need to be protected by mutex. So using full() without mutext is not a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the queue uses a mutex (or something at least vaguely similar such as memory fences, atomic variables, etc.), yes, this could easily have a problem.

Just for example, let's assume a `queue` defined to use some (single) variable to hold how much space is currently available in the queue. So, your `push` and `pop` have code something like:

```
push(item) {
    --space_avail;
    // ...
}

pop() {
    ++space_avail;
}
```

When written like this, the problem may not be obvious, so let's look at what kind of code we might expect to see:

```
// --space_avail
mov r0, space_avail
dec r0
mov space_avail, r0

// ++ space_avail
mov r0, space_avail
inc r0
mov space_avail, r0
```

Now the problem is probably more apparent. If our produce and consumer threads overlap like this:

```
T0: mov r0, space avail
T1: mov r0, space_avail
T1: dec r0
T1: mov space_avail, r0
T0: inc r0
T0: mov space_avail, r0
```

If we do a push and a pop, we expect `space_avail` to end up with the same value it started with--but in this case, it doesn't; it comes out one larger than it started out. You can probably also pretty easily see where swapping the dec/store sequence and the inc/store sequence would reverse that, so `space_avail` would come out smaller than it started.

Clearly either of these leads to a queue that doesn't work corectly.

Answer (score 0):

**NO**

First, queue::full is not a part of std, so if you're using a custom queue, we can't answer that question without knowing the internal implementation.

Second, in your pseudo code, if the queue has for example 1 item in it, and hypothetical size is 8, both conditions will be satisfied and both will enter their logic. Despite your naming of the methods, both functions perform a write operation, because both queue::pop and queue::push changes the state of the queue object.

And if two concurrent threads modify a single object, you always has to use mutex to ensure consistency of data.

Comment: I was thinking implementing full() function by myself, then I figured out that full() and empty() will need counter to decide whether it is empty or full, while this counter also need to be protected by mutex. So using full() without mutext is not a good approach.